# Dough loses flexibility and strength once mixed with starter and starts raising

Tags: bread, sourdough

I've watched many videos on making sourdough bread and in most of the cases it looks like the elasticity and strength of the dough is not affected by the starter.

In my case, it doesn't work like that.

I first mix flour with water and leave it for at least an hour, sometimes a couple of hours, then add the starter and leave it raise.

Once I add the starter, I leave it for about 1h before pulling the edges to the centre to make it stronger. The thing is that from that moment on, it's not that flexible like before I added the starter. What's more, if I leave it for a few hours to raise, then it's like a thick juice, so I can't create a consistent loaf. As a result, I just put it in a pyrex and once raised put it as is in the oven.

Recipe is ~600g mixed flour, 400ml water, 200gr starter.

Last but not least, it doesn't raise much once put in the oven, so no need for that cut before putting it in the oven, as it's shown in various videos.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: How did you develop your starter, what is your feeding schedule, and what is the hydration % of your starter?

Comment: @moscafj I make bread once per 5-7 days. I put it out of the fridge in the evening and feed it (80gr dark rye flour, 80ml water), use it after 12-18/h when it's ~X2 in volume. In the remaining one, I put another 80gr flour + 80ml water, put it in the fridge until next time. It won't double in the fridge until next time

Comment: When do you add salt?

Comment: When I put the starter. Last time actually I put it later, after it raised but it was already not strong anymore. I saw a video where the guy is suggesting both the % of the starter and the acidity could affect it. I can leave it less time to raise but it wont much and it doesn't much either when put in the oven.